# why does the first version print newline as 129 but the second works just fine?

Tags: c, printf, negative-number, zero-initialization

when I run the first program, `nl` (newline) is set to 7ff, and prints out 129.

```
#include<stdio.h>
// countblanks-tabs-newlinesv1.c
void main()
{
    long int c;
    unsigned char nl, space, tab = 0  ;

    while( ( c = getchar() ) != EOF) 
    {
        if ( c == '\n') 
        {
            nl++;
        }
        if ( c == ' ')
        {
            space++;
        }
        if ( c == '\t')
        {
            tab++;
        }
    }
    printf("input has %d newlines, %d spaces and %d tabs\n", nl, space, tab);


}
```

But when I run the second program everything works fine...I think.

Second program

```
#include<stdio.h>
// countblanks-tabs-newlinesv2.c
void main()
{
    long int c;
    char space, tab ;
    int nl;
    nl = 0;
    space = 0 ;
    tab = 0;

    while( ( c = getchar() ) != EOF) 
    {
        if ( c == '\n') 
        {
            nl++;
        }
        if ( c == ' ')
        {
            space++;
        }
        if ( c == '\t')
        {
            tab++;
        }
    }
    printf("input has %d newlines, %d spaces and %d tabs\n", nl, space, tab);


}
```

btw this is exercise 1-8 in [**The C Programming Language**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628) Book

Answer (score 3):

You didn't initialize `nl` and `space` to `0` in the first version. They have unpredictable initial values, so you get an unpredictable total.

When you write

```
unsigned char nl, space, tab = 0  ;
```

the `= 0` initializer only applies to `tab`, not all the variables. You need to provide an initial value to each of them:

```
unsigned char nl = 0, space = 0, tab = 0  ;
```

Comment: Another reason why using commas to squash these variable declarations together is ugly.  Just give them each their own declaration.